# how to fix hh601 error i am getting error while run the contract

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, hardhat

Error HH601: Script scripts/buy-coffee.js doesn't exist. when  I try to run smart contract  it shows the hh601 error while run in the terminal how to fix the error

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you got the buy-coffee.js in the scripts folder
If it is there then, run it via this command,

```
npx hardhat run ./scripts/buy-coffee.js
```

don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: its in script folder but still getting error hh601

Comment: share the file structure and your console directory are you sure you are in the project folder?